# Comparing two values to return the max, and populate another table with the value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to populate a table which includes fields:

```
EmpPositioniTrent
EffectiveDate
ManPositioniTrent
```

The two position numbers are from one table, and `EffectiveDate` is populated with the latest/most recent `StartDate` associated with the position numbers, located in another table.

From this table: I retrieve the two Position numbers

[image]

And then using this table below, I join on the Person number, and I want to (using the fields PersonNumber and ManPerNo from the table above) which of those has the later Start Date, and use that to populate the EffectiveDate field in my new table.

[image]

I have got this far:

```
SELECT 
a.EmpPositioniTrent, 
a.ManPositioniTrent, 
MAX(b.StartDate) AS EffectiveDate
FROM [dbo].[STG_People_Manager] a
JOIN [dbo].[STG_0001_ORGANISATION_ASSIGNMENT] b 
ON a.PersonNumber = b.PersonNumber
WHERE b.EndDate >= GETDATE()
```

I am wondering if I need to use a `CTE` or `(SELECT) AS` to achieve this, but I am completely stuck! I have tried to use `MAX` date but cannot use it properly or effectively because I cannot find a way to compare them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I realise that I have not explained this well but I have done my best!

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result from that sample data.

Comment: Agree with @Viki888.  See the top answer to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for some tips on posting SQL questions.

Comment: I've tried to provide some sample data. Probably not very well, let me know if more is required... @Viki888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case it helps anyone else, I am posting how I did it here, and hopefully will explain it better than I explained the question..

I had a table (A) which included columns:

```
EmpPositionNumber | ManagerPositionNumber
```

In another table (B) was a list of all

```
 PositionNumbers | StartDates
```

(with no differentiation between manager and emp)

To populate a third table (C) with columns:

```
EmpPositionNumber | EffectiveDate | ManPositionNumber
```

I needed to compare the **StartDates** in Table B for the two position numbers from each row of Table A to be able to populate the **EffectiveDate** in Table C with the latest date.

To achieve this, in the end, I populated a fourth table D:

```
EmpPositionNumber | ManPositionNumber | StartDate
```

and this was populated with two rows for each one row in table A, with the **StartDate** from Table B being different for the two rows, e.g.:

```
EmpPositionNumber | ManPositionNumber | StartDate
    A             |       Aa          | 12/1/2016
    A             |       Aa          | 15/3/2015
    B             |       Xa          | 4/1/2013
    B             |       Xa          | 18/5/2016
```

Then to Populate Table C,  I took the **EmpPositionNumber** and **ManPositionNumber**, and the **MAX(StartDate) GROUP BY EmpPositionNumber, ManPositionNumber**

I hope that makes sense and is properly explained.

Answer (score 0):

If this is `SQL Server`, I don't recall there is a `SELECT AS`

```
INSERT INTO <<table>> (PositionNumber, ManagerPositionNumber, EffectiveDate)
SELECT 
a.EmpPositioniTrent 
a.ManPositioniTrent 
MAX(b.StartDate)
FROM [dbo].[STG_People_Manager] a
JOIN [dbo].[STG_0001_ORGANISATION_ASSIGNMENT] b 
ON a.PersonNumber = b.PersonNumber
WHERE b.EndDate >= GETDATE()
GROUP BY a.EmpPositioniTrent, b.ManPositioniTrent
```